# r count the number of nonmissing entries per variable per ID

Tags: r, dplyr, count

Suppose this is my dataset

```
ID      Creatinine   Albumin   Calcium
1       12.2         10.1      NA
1       10.3          8.3      0.33
2       NA           11.12     0.56
2       5.6           9.6      0.14
2       NA            NA       NA
3       4.2          10.16     0.67
3       NA           12.84     0.45
4       NA           NA        0.72
```

I am interested in creating a summary of count indicating the number of times a given variable was measured per ID, like this

```
ID      Creatinine   Albumin   Calcium
1       2            2         1    
2       2            2         2  
3       1            2         2
4       NA           NA        1
```

Any suggestion regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
t(sapply(split(df[-1], f = df$ID), function(x) colSums(!is.na(x))))
```

**Output**

```
  Creatinine Albumin Calcium
1          2       2       1
2          1       2       2
3          1       2       2
4          0       0       1
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L),
      Creatinine = c(12.2, 10.3, NA, 5.6, NA, 4.2, NA, NA),
      Albumin = c(10.1, 8.3, 11.12,
                  9.6, NA, 10.16, 12.84, NA),
      Calcium = c(NA, 0.33, 0.56, 0.14,
                  NA, 0.67, 0.45, 0.72)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-8L)
  )
```

Comment: I am seeing a warning ,`In split.default(x=seq_len(nrow(x)), f=f, drop=drop,...): data length is not a multiple of split variable`. This may be something specific with my dataset I am investigating this.

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai I'm unsure without seeing the full dataframe to see where the issue might be occuring. But in `f = ...`, you do have to make sure that you use the dataframe explicitly, i.e., `df$ID`.

Comment: thanks Andrew, I am defining it explicitly, but I will dig into this a bit more

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai So, I'm guessing the issue is that you transformed the dataframe into a `data.table` when you did Merijan's solution. After I converted to a data.table and tried to run the code, I got the same error. So, if you just convert back to a dataframe, `df <- as.data.frame(df)`, then it should work fine.

Comment: perfect, you are absolutely correct. That solution worked.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a more concise base R way, but here's one with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(!is.na(.))))


# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID Creatinine Albumin Calcium
  <int>      <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1          2       2       1
2     2          1       2       2
3     3          1       2       2
4     4          0       0       1
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Springs dplyr is giving me an error, " `across() must only be used inside dplyr verbs`

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai This is probably because it is trying to use `plyr` with `summarize` rather than `dplyr`. To get around that, you can just make the call explicit, i.e., `dplyr::summarize`, then it will probably work as normal.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown. you are absolutely right, adding dplyr:: solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), by = ID, .SDcols = !"ID"]

#    ID Creatinine Albumin Calcium
# 1:  1          2       2       1
# 2:  2          1       2       2
# 3:  3          1       2       2
# 4:  4          0       0       1
```

In case that you  really want the zero counts to be displayed as NA

```
dt[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) { x <- sum(!is.na(x)); if (x == 0) x <- as.integer(NA); x }), by = ID, .SDcols = !"ID"]

#    ID Creatinine Albumin Calcium
# 1:  1          2       2       1
# 2:  2          1       2       2
# 3:  3          1       2       2
# 4:  4         NA      NA       1
```

Comment: perfect this worked without any error or warning.